# Am I using ContinueWith correctly?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I have an application with a startup window (in WPF) which lets the user log in, choose a database, make some other settings, and eventually (upon success) shows a progress bar. When the progress is done, a main window (in WinForms) is shown instead.

To make the progress bar update smoothly, I'm separating as much as I can away from the UI thread. Here's the current approach:

```
var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
var backgroundScheduler = TaskScheduler.Default;

var connectingTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("connecting started");

    // some code that connects to a server; may fail

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("connecting finishing");
}

var connectFailAction = new Action<Task>((t) =>
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("connectFail started");

    // let user know that connecting failed, then exit

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("connectFail finishing");
});

var postConnectAction = new Action<Task>((t) =>
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("postConnect started");

    // some initial post-connection setup code; runs in UI thread

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("postConnect finishing");
});

var dbLoadingAction = new Action<Task>((t) =>
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("dbLoading started");

    // code that loads settings from the database; runs in background

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("dbLoading finishing");
});

var runGuiAction = new Action<Task>((t) =>
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("runGui started");

    // set up the main form, show it, hide this startup progress window

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("runGui finishing");
});

connectingTask.ContinueWith(connectFailAction,
                            System.Threading.CancellationToken.None,
                            TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted,
                            uiScheduler);

connectingTask.ContinueWith(postConnectAction,
                            System.Threading.CancellationToken.None,
                            TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
                            uiScheduler)
              .ContinueWith(dbLoadingAction,
                            System.Threading.CancellationToken.None,
                            TaskContinuationOptions.None,
                            backgroundScheduler)
              .ContinueWith(runGuiAction,
                            System.Threading.CancellationToken.None,
                            TaskContinuationOptions.None,
                            uiScheduler);
```

If the connection fails, the task goes straight to `connectFailAction`.

Otherwise, on the UI thread, `postConnectAction` is run next, while simultaneously, `dbLoadingAction` is run in the background. Afterwards, `runGuiAction` is run.

This mostly works fine, but one odd edge case where it breaks down is `CefSharp`. Specifically, non-CefSharp portions of the UI are 'stuck' — I can't resize the form, I can't interact with any controls, etc.

Since equivalent code works fine with the WinForms `WebBrowser` control, I'm guessing it's partially an issue with CefSharp, but part of it may be my incorrect use/understanding of the TPL.

If I change the code as follows, the UI gets stuck during loading (unsurprisingly), but CefSharp inits correctly.

```
connectingTask.ContinueWith(connectFailAction,
                            System.Threading.CancellationToken.None,
                            TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted,
                            uiScheduler);

connectingTask.Wait();
postConnectAction.Invoke(null);
dbLoadingAction.Invoke(null);
runGuiAction.Invoke(null);
```

If (and only if) using CefSharp, the main thread is stuck in `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherSynchronizationContext.Wait`, so I'm guessing one of the above tasks never cleanly finishes, causing an event queue not to flush properly?

Comment: Just want to make sure that you know that the code would be much simpler and obviously correct with await.

Answer (score 1):

> The main thread is stuck in `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherSynchronizationContext.Wait`, so I'm guessing one of the above tasks never cleanly finishes, causing an event queue not to flush properly?

The problem is your code deadlocks in the latter example. You're invoking the `Task` which later attempts to run the continuation on the UI thread, which is currently blocked by `connectingTask.Wait();`. This is why [you shouldn't block on async code.](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Regarding CefSharp, perhaps the continuation you're running on the UI thread after connecting is CPU intensive and causing your UI message loop to halt for more than a reasonable amount of time. Can't be sure since you haven't provided the relevant code.